# Exception "cannot track multiple objects with the same key" when attaching empty PK entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm adding/updating rows in database with Attach in EF 5 Database first.

It works well for entities that doesn't exist in database yet.
When trying to attach existing entity, it throws me exception `An object with the same key already exists in the ObjectStateManager. The ObjectStateManager cannot track multiple objects with the same key.`.

I've tried extensions as in other answers here, and no one worked.

The note is that I'm attaching a entity without setting the PK, I don't have this info from implemented code.

Code

```
var db = new XXX_DevEntities();
int YearMax = DateTime.Today.AddYears(5).Year;
var existent = (from a in db.BusinessDays
               where a.Year < YearMax
               select new { a.Year, a.Month }).ToList();
foreach (var aj in ajustes)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        var entidade = new BusinessDays { Year = aj.Year, Month = i };
        db.BusinessDays.Attach(entidade);               // THROWS EXCEPTION HERE
        entidade.Qtd = aj.ValorMonth(i);
        db.Entry(entidade).State = existent.Contains(new { Year = aj.Year, Month = i }) ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found how..

I've choosed another approach and I'm attaching the entity with PK, by retrieving it from database (actually, from Local cache of db set).

```
var db = new XXX_DevEntities();
int YearMax = DateTime.Today.AddYears(5).Year;
var existent = (from a in db.BusinessDays
               where a.Year < YearMax
               select a).ToList();
foreach (var aj in ajustes)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
        var codBusinessDay = diasUteisExistentes.Where(x => x.Year == aj.Year && x.Month == i).Select(x => x.CodBusinessDay).FirstOrDefault();
        var entidade = new BusinessDays { CodBusinessDay = codBusinessDay };
        db.BusinessDays.Attach(entidade);
        entidade.Year = aj.Year;
        entidade.Month = i;
        entidade.Qtd = aj.ValorMonth(i);
        db.Entry(entidade).State = codBusinessDay > 0 ? EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    }
}

db.SaveChanges();
```